# Site has gone very slow after upgrading WordPress version to 5.7.1 with all plugins updated

Tags: wordpress, performance, upgrade, updates

I have a WordPress site which was loading normally before I upgraded its WordPress version to 5.7.1 with all plugins being updated. Now, site is loading very slow. Is this upgradation has to do anything with the site's performance?

This is the site: https://bonculina.se/

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No necessarily, but if your hosting service is offering less bandwidth then there are chances that after the update the website becomes slow.

What you can do?

Downgrade your WordPress to the last version. Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/

If things don't work fine, you should contact your Hosting provider.